# Azure B2C - renew session

Tags: reactjs, azure, session, azure-ad-b2c, session-timeout

I have a React app that uses Azure B2C to authenticate users (PKCE flow).
There is a requirement to keep the session active as long as the user has some activity.

I cannot use "Rolling" for session timeout, because some of the requests are made by an independent job, which is not triggered by the user.

Here is my question - how can I control renewing the session? I would like to renew the session every time I am getting the access token.

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens and ID tokens are short-lived. Since you are using the Authorization-Code Grant flow of OAuth, after they expire, you must refresh them to continue to access resources .

Hence in order to get the refresh-token, you would have to send a POST request to the `/token` endpoint of B2C with the scope .(i.e; Provide the `refresh_token` instead of the code in the rquest).see reference 1.

Make sure to add scopes along with AppId  'openid profile offline_access AppId’

Ex: scope: 'openid profile offline_access XXXXXX-f9a4-4b8e-XXXX-dXXXXXXX01f'

**References:**

1. [Authorization code flow - Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft
   Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow#4-refresh-the-token)
2. [microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/FAQ (github.com)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-browser/FAQ.md#how-do-i-acquire-a-refresh-token)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm new in the B2C, so could you please tell me how getting the refresh token is related to renewing/extending the session?